# How to modify an email from woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem to modify an email which I send with the woocommerce template. I can't find the file in the woocommerce folder to modify.

Comment: just look more, and read the woocommerce documentation ;-) you will find it

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-email-templates/

Within Wordpress you can navigate to `"WooCoommerce> Settings> Emails"` and edit basic information there.

You can also edit the template file from this location.

Comment: It doesnt appears the edit html in emails on woocommerce, i dont know why